# Hyperledger composer network upgrade timout error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am getting this error while upgrading bna file on network:-
Error trying to upgrade business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
Any solution to this?
first i installed the initial version of bna file and start the network and it works perfect with these commands:-

> composer network install -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -a medicalprovenance@0.0.0.bna
>
> composer network start --networkName medicalprovenance
> --networkVersion 0.0.0 -A admin -S adminpw -c
> PeerAdmin@hlfv1

but when i tried to upgrade the network with these commands :-

> composer network install -a medicalprovenance@0.0.1.bna -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1
>
> composer network upgrade --networkName medicalprovenance --networkVersion
> 0.0.1 -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1

it fails with timeout error as described in question
I am using fabric dev server single organisation network.

name and version information in package.json file is:-
"name":"medicalprovenance","version":"0.0.1"

docker ps -a output is:-

5d86afea3b9f        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-medicalprovenance-0.0.0-fccf8faa81606e91484c24fcd1f851b4d93c9632dce32d2ff3a90b0f12ed12f4   "/bin/sh -c 'cd /usr…"   24 minutes ago      Up 24 minutes                                                        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-medicalprovenance-0.0.0
a9d40b271b2c        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0                                                                                  "peer node start"        26 minutes ago      Up 26 minutes       0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
c1b90e2f062f        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.1.0                                                                               "orderer"                26 minutes ago      Up 26 minutes       0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.example.com
795e16cdaca1        hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.1.0                                                                                    "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   26 minutes ago      Up 26 minutes       0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca.org1.example.com
f5c65f2cce16        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-0.4.6                                                                               "tini -- /docker-ent…"   26 minutes ago      Up 26 minutes       4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp       couchdb

Comment: sorry, you need to provide more detail - as laid out here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#issue  - also need to say what steps you took leading up to this thanks

Comment: i have edited the question ,please check it now.

Comment: can you paste the "name" and "version" info from your package.json (in your bna file). Can you  paste the output of `docker ps -a ` thanks . Are you using Composer 0.19.12 ??

Comment: i am using composer 0.19.8 and i have pasted version , name info (from bna file ) and  docker ps -a output in question.

Comment: Strange you're seeing this issue on a localhost? Is there some docker routing issue? See https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#information_source--composer-network-start-issues for assistance (scroll down to the REQUEST_TIMEOUT answer and see the changes required). You could try increasing the timeout to 2400s as suggested. I would otherwise suggest to do a `teardownFabric.sh` ( get the latest fabric-dev-servers tooling from [install page](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html) and..

Comment: contd... try again (also would suggest to go with latest Composer v0.19.12 - ie npm uninstall -g and then npm install -g your modules). Make sure you also remove your $HOME/.composer directory after the teardown (above).

Comment: i have solved this issue by increasing the timeout in connection.json file from 300 to 1200.Thanks for your help :)